# How to implement tab activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tabactivity

I had already started with a blank activity but now i want to use a tab activity instead is there any way of converting the blank activity to a tab activity

Comment: Yes-  just write the code for tabs in there.  Tab activity doesn't do anything magical, it just adds some boilerplate code.

Comment: What is the code that should go there and where should it go

Comment: There is many tutorial... check http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Answer (score 0):

Learn it from the example. 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

It is made by Chris Banes for Google I/O 2015 event session: Android Design Support Library: Bringing material design to life. 
https://events.google.com/io2015/schedule?sid=e958a197-b6d4-e411-b87f-00155d5066d7#day1/e958a197-b6d4-e411-b87f-00155d5066d7

Start with searching "category 1" in the repository.

Let me know if you get any problem.